# Checkbox não clicavel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Quero deixar os checkbox de uma página em especifico do meu site visiveis, porem não clicaveis, onde o usuário só poderá interagir com eles após se logar. Existe alguma solução em CSS para essa situação em especifico? Tipo a classe .disabled que existe no bootstrap para buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o próprio *HTML*, com o recurso `disabled`.

```html
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" disabled name="1" value="">Desabilitado<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="">Habilitado
</form>
```